# Filebeat sent Logs to Logstash thought nginx proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to make Filbeat sending logs to Logstash using docker containers.
The problem is that I have an nginx proxy in between and Filbeat-Logstash communication is not based on HTTPS.
What is the solutions to make it working?

I was trying to make nginx able to process tcp streams configuring it in this way:

```
stream {
  upstream logs {
    server logstash:5044;
  }

  server {
    listen 5088;
    proxy_pass logs;
  }
}
```

And this is my filebeat output config:

```
output.logstash:
    hosts: ["IP_OF_NGINX:5088"]
    ssl.verification_mode: none
```

But it seems not to work.
Filebeat shows me this error in its logs:
pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://IP_OF_NGINX:5088)): dial tcp IP_OF_NGINX:5088: connect: connection refused

Any help?

Comment: remove the nginx proxy between filebeat and logstash , it is not needed

Comment: Does your Nginx server have firewall rules ? Is the port 5088 allowed for connections from your docker container host ?